# How long will double cream stay whipped?

Tags: cream, whipped-cream

I'd like to prepare some whipped double cream in advance for a dessert I'm making. How long will the cream stay whipped (i.e. peaky) if I do it in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you whisk very cold cream in a very cold bowl, and keep it very cold, it should hold for about 3-4 hours. Longer than that and it can start to separate.

Comment: Great, thanks, you've saved me having a messy disaster.